# Is there is any code for Adding Ip adddres in wordpress for user

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there is any custom code for adding an IP address in WordPress for all users or also to allow WordPress site’s users to be allowed to add IPs using which they can auto-login to their respective accounts?

Comment: "adding IP address for all users" - what do you mean by this?  Are you asking for a configuration where people who aren't using that IP address cannot use your wordpress instance?  Also what do you mean by "auto-login" - do you want people from specific IP addresses do not have to enter credentials?  That isn't a very good security practice.

Comment: I mean that when the user login to the WordPress site using wocommerce login. In their section drop down like my account. There need an Option is Add IP Address  And I want to add the IP address for a specific user

Comment: I understand you want to add an IP address.  It would help me if you can explain *why* you need their IP address.  IP addresses are usually dynamic (i.e. they change over time), and are not a reliable way to identify people or establish trust.  If you can articulate *why* you want this, perhaps I can help you find a better solution to your requirement.

Comment: I need functionality as same as a plugin of Ip based login plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip-based-login/) That plugin is using adding the IP address of the user on the admin dashboard side( Back end side). I need that functionality on the Frond end side. This is my Requirement. Please Help me with that @Michael

Comment: I would never trust an IP address in place of a credential to authenticate an identity, and cannot recommend and solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

### You're looking for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

> `'REMOTE_ADDR'`
> The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

Learn more about `$_SERVER` @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

---

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will get you your user IP, you can now create a new custom meta box for each user with the remote address as value.

Keep in mind that more and more providers are giving users modular IPs, YOU even, probably have a modular IP. VPN are also a thing, so IPs are pretty much pointless to collect.

If you're living in the EU, bear in mind that collecting unnecessary datas with no end point can be fined since the introduction of the RGPD law.